# Accessing flink state within Window via queryable state or storing state after each window aggregation

Tags: apache-flink

I am using apache flink to aggregate kafka stream on certain amount of time based windows.
After window expires, data will be saved to storage and this is all implemented via this structure:

```
        SingleOutputStreamOperator<Aggregator> stream = source
                .forceNonParallel()
                .keyBy(Object::getKey)
                .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(5)))
                .aggregate(new CustomAggregator(), new KeyedWindowFunction("m5"));
```

Now my requirement is to have access to window state at any point in time in order to retrieve it because I am showing realtime chart on UI.

So for example, in this case only after 5 mins have expired will object be saved to data storage and be eligibale for access and that means that users will only see last 5 minutes and not the current aggregation which is non ideal.

As far as I see there are 2 options:

- Either flink exposes way to access window state via queryable state
- Or I need to create custom state object and on each element after aggregation store this into the state object so I can retrieve it via queryable state.
- ProcessWindowFunction has access to context and state, but its called only after window has expired which is no use to me since at that point, data will be put into sink.

Problem with second approach is that AggregateFunction called in .aggregate() does not have access to context and so I cannot save it there.

So the question is, is there a wat to combine: window, AggregateFunction, and be able to store each aggregation of wndow into custom state object?